# Data Modeling for Power BI

Tags: powerbi, data-modeling, star-schema

I believe I have a data modelling problem since I can't connect my fact table with my ABC dimension. I just tried several things but nothing seems to work, so I am searching for some improvement tips, if you can help. I am also new using power BI. I have two excel files that I use to create the model.

This is a material flow. I would like to show it in a flow map. So, I have a material that is sold from company located in country A to company located in country B. This material can have a certain ABC classification for company A but a different ABC classification for company B.

Ex) Material 001 is A for China and B for Germany. For example, my Source can be Austria that sends this material to China and Germany.

I have the following tables:

```
Dimension Source and Destination (ID, Source Country, Destination Country, City, Postal Code, etc)
Dimension Material (ID, description)
Dimension ABC & Status (material ID, Source and Destination ID, ABC classification, Status)
Fact (Order Qty, Price in Eur, etc)
```

Therefore, one Material can have many ABC classification.
A single source can send a material to several destinations. A destination can also have multiple sources.

[image]

I also thought of just connecting ABC directly to the fact dimension by using a composed key with material and source/destination. However, I think it is conceptually wrong. In this case, I am able to see the data in a table, it works. But as soon as I plot the graph, everything blocks. I think a dimension is not supposed to be so big...
Figuring out the right relationship should be the right approach, I guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would remove or deactivate the other relationships for Dim ABC, then connect it directly to the fact as you described.

The relationship definition needs to be **1 to many** (Dim ABC to Fact).

For your graph challenge, you'll need to give more info.